# TYPO3 Symfony Expression: isset() for POST of array

Tags: symfony, typoscript, typo3-9.x

How can a TypoScript condition be formed to check if a POST parameter has been sent with a non empty value?

In TYPO3 until 8.7 I have this condition:

```
[globalVar = GP:ttp_basket != '']
plugin.tt_products = USER_INT
[global]
```

In TYPO3 9 and 10 I want to do the same by

```
[traverse(request.getParsedBody()['ttp_basket'])]
plugin.tt_products = USER_INT
[global]
```

However it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

It works with another expression format.

```
[traverse(request.getParsedBody(), 'ttp_basket')]
plugin.tt_products = USER_INT
[global]
```

There has been a syntax error in the previously used format.
"traverse" requires 2 parameters: array and string